# using ajax to upload files from dropzone.js programatically

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I need to upload a file with dropzone and then manually submit it to the sever with my $.ajax call, no dropzone urls. I need to get the image data programatically and add it to the $.ajax call.

Basically I have a wrapper div which I use for the dropzone.

Then I can use a separate click event for a button which builds a custom $.ajax post.

I can access the dropzone file with myDropzone.files[0] but it doesn't give me the raw data. How can I access the actual file?

Comment: I may have done something similar. I used `autoProcessQueue: false` and hooked into the events "addedfile", "thumbnail", and "queuecomplete". Then resized using canvas then uploaded my resized image.